# C pointer trouble: it loses address information when returned from a function

Tags: c, pointers

I have some C code here where a pointer is allocated and returned to the parent caller/parent function. Using GDB, I noticed that the pointer allocation is fine but when I return it, it loses the high bits of the first four bytes of the address. Basically it goes like this:

```
allocate pointer A
allocate pointer B
Free A
Return B
```

Now, if I change this to:

```
allocate pointer B
allocate pointer A
Free A
Return B
```

Things work fine. What is strange is that this code worked fine for 5+ years and now it is giving us trouble on some very specific cases. What worries us is that the address is changed, we could not detect this error in any other way, only when we attached gdb and started looking around we saw the change.

Anyone here seen something similar or knows why this is happening? By the way, we are not trying to write more than we can handle in A or B, both buffers are the right size for the data.

thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without any code to inspect.

Comment: You don't `allocate a pointer`, you `allocate data that is referenced by a pointer`.

Comment: Without code, my suspicion is that your "buffers" are not actually the right size for the pointers (just the fact that you called them "buffers" makes me suspicious).

Comment: code isn't mine, it is my boss code. Sorry for saying "allocate a pointer", english is not my native language, I actually know how pointers work and for calling them buffers, sorry again, all I wanted to say is that some chunk of memory is allocated and a pointer to that place is passed around, this works every time except for couple simple cases. I can't post the code right now since it is not mine to post but the comments gave me a clue on what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

Smells like you didn't declare a prototype of your function. This went well for years on 32bit machines where `int` and `void*` have the same width. Nowadays these are different, and you loose your high order bytes.

You compile with `-Wall` or something like that, I suppose?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check the source and compiler directives.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to many reasons, overflow of buffers, limited heap space etc. Posting code would help!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost surely due to memory corruption, i.e. writing to random addresses or past the end of an allocated object or object on the stack.

Comment: I wondered about that as well when I was investigating overflows. So far is pretty odd. Thanks for the answer.